What am I missing in this paragraph from "The Bear With the Knot on His Tail?"
This is the opening paragraph to Steven Tall's The Bear With the Knot on His Tail:

We swept in comfortable wide orbit around Earth, thirty thousand miles beyond the moon. Cap’n Jules Griffin kept us in the moon shadow, the umbra, a pleasanter location in which to drift and listen than out in the raw yellow radiance of Sol. Only a few degrees away from the moon’s vast shadowy disk the full Earth hung like a color plate, blue, cloud-shrouded, the most majestic object I’ve ever seen from space.

I'm having difficulty picturing this alignment where you're in the moon's shadow, but only a few degrees away one can see the full earth.  This seems like kind of a rudimentary mistake for a hard SF writer, so my guess is that I'm misinterpreting it somehow.  I'd believe it's a mistake if something in the opening paragraph didn't match a comment on page 20, but this is three sentences.
Maybe "full Earth" isn't meant to mean "mostly illuminated" as in "full Moon," but I'm not sure how else to interpret it, particularly with the described color palate. Anyone have any insights for me here?
Edit:  It's probably worth clarifying here that I'm familiar with the astronomy involved, I'm not asking a "real world science" question...I'm looking for some way to interpret the above paragraph so it makes sense.  If the answer is "Tall got it wrong," I'll accept it, but I wanted to see if anyone could give an alternative interpretation where there's no mistake.

There is nowhere you could be a) outside the moon's orbit and b) in the moon's shadow where you could see an illuminated Earth. You would have to be on its dark side.

"Dark side" is a bit ambiguous here, generally referring to the far side, which is no more literally dark than the near side.  If that's the source of the confusion, it's not on my end, it's on Tall's head.

You would be on the side that is literally dark, that is to say unlit

If you're in the Moon's shadow but you can see a Full Earth, then you're between the Moon & the Earth. So the Earth's (roughly) in the opposite direction to the Moon, not a few degrees from it. (I could write a proper answer, but we don't normally do Real World Science answers here).

It's strange that it says the moon's umbra, which would make the vessel be between the moon and the Earth, but the paragraph also says "thirty thousand miles beyond the moon", which would place the vessel outside the moon's orbit. Maybe the author had an initial thought, then changed his mind, and forgot to update some of the text (and it wasn't caught by his editor?).

@AndresF. Good point. The ship definitely can't be beyond the Moon, relative to Earth. FWIW, the Moon's umbra cone is long enough to reach the Earth, which is how we get total solar eclipses.

@PM2Ring wait, I think I got it wrong. The moon's umbra can project into space, depending on the position of the moon and Earth relative to the Sun, so it's possible for a body to be in the moon's umbra and not be between the moon and the Earth.

@Andres But for the ship in the Moon's umbra to see a Full Earth, the alignment has to be roughly like S--------M-*-E, where S, M, E are Sun, Moon, Earth, and * is the ship. Note that the Sun-Earth distance is ~370 times the Earth-Moon distance, so it's not easy to do a proper scale drawing. ;)

In my diagram below, the Moon is the gray circle and the ship is the square near the Moon.
This is the only way the ship would be in the umbra and still see the Earth next to the Moon.

As you can see, the Earth would not be seen as full.

Ah! I got it wrong, I thought the moon's umbra was only its shadow cone projected on Earth. Now I see it's possible for the ship to be in the umbra and farther away from Earth than the moon.

As you say, this doesn't meet the description in the book.

I can't think of a configuration that meets all of the book's description. You have the right idea if the "few degrees" reference is important. But it's the wrong configuration if the "full Earth" reference is important - that configuration requires the Earth to be on the other side of the ship (below the ship, left or right, in your drawing). As shown, the Earth would be an illuminated crescent. However, this would be neither the first time nor the last that an author played loosey-goosey with the facts. It's better known as "literary license."

Note that I recognized your use of technology to overcome the crescent Earth problem - but the book doesn't mention it (at least in this paragraph), so it isn't applicable. Creative, though. Cheers.

@JBH which use of technology? (genuine question, I find this question and the ensuing discussion fascinating!)

I'm familiar with how sunshine works...for the question, I'm largely asking if anyone can come up with a way to interpret that paragraph so it's accurate.

@CristobolPolychronopolis write that in your question... a comment to an answer is not the place for it

Was doing that just now, but didn't think leaving the redundant comment would hurt.  If I'm wrong, I'll delete it.

@AndresF. My comment was made obsolete by an edit by Jstola. In the original answer we find, One way for Earth to be full, is by use of technology to reflect sunlight onto the dark side of the Earth. My comment was in reference to Jstola's effort to resolve the problem with the paragraph, which I believe was nothing more than literary license. No SciFi story, no matter how science-based, is perfect. Science in its purest form renders most stories boring.
